# Replacing a specific pattern of values at level 2 in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

I've a list of lists,

```
tl = {{True, False, m12}, {False, m22, m33}, {m32, False, True}}
```

and each nested list has the same length, What is the proper way to replace the occurances of all `m*` values, i.e., `m12`, `m22`, etc., with a particular value say `x`.

All I want is this result

> ```
> tl = {{True, False, x}, {False, x, x}, {x, False, True}}`
> ```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything other than `True, False` and `m*`?

Comment: No there are only True, False or m*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One rather literal (string-based) interpretation of your question:

```
tl = {{True, False, m12}, {False, m22, m33}, {m32, False, True}};

tl /. s_ /; StringTake[ToString[s], 1] == "m" :> X
```

> {{True, False, X}, {False, X, X}, {X, False, True}}

Answer (score 11):

```
tl = {{True, False, m12}, {False, m22, m33}, {m32, False, True}};

Replace[tl, Except[True | False] :> z, {2}]

(* {{True, False, z}, {False, z, z}, {z, False, True}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this way the True and False conditions are analyzed

```
tl = {{True, False, m12}, {False, m22, m33}, {m32, False, True}}; 
Map[If[ToString[#1] == "True" || ToString[#1] == "False", #1, 
   x] & , tl, {2}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{True} & \text{False} & x \\
>  \text{False} & x & x \\
>  x & \text{False} & \text{True} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$